Material Utilities not listed in preferences
I want to use the Material Utilities and read in the documentation and online, that I have to enable it in preferences -> Add-ons, but it simply is not there as obvious from the screenshot. It is blender 4.2 freshly donwloaded and installed on Windows 10, it also not filtered out, as depicted on the screenshot.
I used an older version of blender on a linux device before and there I simply had to check the box in that view.

Note: while the linked anwer has the same base problem, from a user perspective one would not find that solution.

Interestingly I figured it out myself. It seems to no longer be bundled per default, but you have to download it. For that go to "Get Extensions" and search for "Material Utilities" and install it for that. Do do that, you have to enable the use of network communication.

This applies to many of the built-in addons from Blender 4.2.

It is always very interesting to watch YT videos where people point out new features and changes in new versions. Things like the new Extensions are often already talked about when the upcoming release is still in Alpha or Beta. Of course then some things might not end up in final versions, but at least you are made aware that there might be something different than before. There are videos on the new extensions system and there have been questions about it here as well.
